# Open/Close an external program

Tags: vbscript, wincc

Working principle: when a button on HMI (Human Machine Interface) is pressed, it will open an external program. If the same button is pressed again, it will close the program. It works like a flip-flop command.
If I use the command "StartProgram", it opens the program, but I don't know how to close the program. I sought a command like "StopProgram" or "CloseProgram", but I wonder it doesn't exist.

So, I'm trying to make this works through a code I've seen on the internet, but unsuccessfully.
Below, my code:

```
Dim PCI
Set PCI = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If SmartTags("Flag Abrir PCI") = 1 Then
    PCI.Run """C:\pret\PCI.exe"" -p1 -c"
End If

If SmartTags("Flag Abrir PCI") = 0 Then
    PCI.Run "taskkill /F /IM PCI.exe", , True
End If
```

Could anyone give me a tip to make it work, please?

When I only write the code below, it opens, but don't know how to close it.

```
StartProgram "C:\pret\PCI.exe", "", hmiShowNormal, hmiNo
```

Comment: This is not standard VBScript it WinCC, the `StartProgram` command is proprietary to that system. See [the documentation](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/mdm/109096785?c=69073381515&dl=en).

Comment: From the documentation it suggests you should use [`StopRuntime`](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/mdm/109096785?c=69073518603&lc=en-GB) to stop the program running on the device.

Comment: WinCC Advanced, Professional or 7.x?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is proprietary code used by [WinCC Professional](https://new.siemens.com/global/en/products/automation/simatic-hmi/hmi-software.html) which is a Siemens product. See the [Official Documentation](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/mdm/109096785?c=74713345163&lc=en-GB) for more information.

Just from a brief look through the documentation, it looks like the [`StopRuntime`](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/mdm/109096785?c=69073518603&lc=en-GB) command is what you are looking for.

> Exits the runtime software and thereby the project running on the HMI device.

```vb
StopRuntime hmiStopRuntime
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like below.

```
Set S = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set X = S.Exec("C:\\pret\\PCI.exe")

'DO SOMETHING

'Closing, Status 0 indicates the executable is still running.
If X.Status = 0 Then X.Terminate()
```